# required php code to download a file from sub folder of a server

Tags: php

say my server is www.abc.com

In my server there is sub folder images
in which one excel file is there i.e. a.xls;
I would like to download this file to my local computer
I need php code for the same

Comment: Do you know _file_get_contents(...)_ or PHP FTP functions (if FTP can be used)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not PHP but I want to share my solution.
How about "wget" on Linux or cygwin on Windows.
1. Create a that list all files needed to dowload "list.txt" (One file one line)
2. Create a shell script file "download.sh"

```
while read file; do
    wget $file
done < /path/to/file/list.txt
```

3. On linux, make "download.sh" available to executed.

```
chmod +x /path/to/file/download.sh
```

4. Execute file

```
./path/to/file/download.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="excelsheet.xls"');
    $file_path = "www.abc.com/image/excelsheet.xls";
    echo file_get_contents($file_path);
?>
```

Save the above code as download.php and execute to download

Comment: above code shows what is in excel file, but I need to download the same file at local computer

Comment: @sanjay have u included header at given in answer, And try you `$file_path` with `http://` include

Comment: Sir My code is as follows and file is in sub folder       header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Database1.xls"');
    $file_path = "http://example.com/images/Database1.xls";
    echo file_get_contents($file_path);

Comment: @sanjay Have u checked $file_path with http:// , Is there any error you are getting

Comment: sir no error, but screen is blank and showing php file name in address bar of browser, I am trying on google chrome browser

Comment: try once in some other browser

Comment: put `ini_set("display_errors", "On");` in your first line of code, it will tell you if any error occurs

Comment: I think you have double semi colon in `$file_path = "example.com/images/Database1.xls";;` this line please confirm

Comment: Sir Now downloading is started but not file from images sub folder which is required some other file is generated and in that there are some warnings